# Cypress function mocking similar to jest.fn

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Im trying out cypress component test in React and Im kinda confused on some basic stuff like how to assert click handlers.

In Jest I can do something like

```
const hideMock = jest.fn();

renderWithProviders(
    <EmployeeCreationWizard
        hide={hideMock}
        isVisible={true}
        employeeId={123}
    />,
);

await cancel();

expect(hideMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

**How can I do the `const hideMock = jest.fn();` with cypress spies?**

This is what I got

```
it.only('invoke hide() once upon clicking on cancel button', () => {
    const hideSpy = cy.spy();
    cy.interceptEmployeeCreationWizard();
    cy.mount(
      <EmployeeCreationWizard
        isVisible={true}
        hide={hideSpy}
        employeeId={123}
      />,
    );

    cy.findByTestId('employee-wizard-drawer-cancel').click();
    cy.get('[data-test-id="employee-wizard-drawer-close"]').click();
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
    // expect(hideSpy).to.be.calledOnce;
  });
```

Comment: Ah missed this https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/react/examples#Testing-Event-Handlers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not worked with component testing much but using spy/stub should be relatively the same. For your case, you'll want to add an alias to your spy/stub, use cy.get('@alias'), and then use sinon assertions against it.

I use .stub() since you want to only check the click handler is called.

```js
it.only('invoke hide() once upon clicking on cancel button', () => {
    cy.interceptEmployeeCreationWizard();
    cy.mount(
      <EmployeeCreationWizard
        isVisible={true}
        hide={cy.stub().as('hide')}
        employeeId={123}
      />,
    );

    cy.findByTestId('employee-wizard-drawer-cancel').click();
    cy.get('[data-test-id="employee-wizard-drawer-close"]').click();
    cy.get('@hide').should('have.been.called')
  });
```

Comment: So cy.stub is similar to jest.fn. Thanks that worked.